# Horizontal lines when clicking the button in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I've some CSS problem in Firefox 3. I have several image buttons on my page and when I'm clicking on them I've seen to horizontal lines across the screen at top and bottom button border. I saw such issue on other web sites, so I think it's something known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the `outline` style in CSS - the idea is that it highlights the element in focus so that people with disabilities notice it better.

You can set the `outline` style to `none` in the css and this should fix it.